Have any formal ontologies focused on the category of knowledge, rather than the content?
The ontologies I am aware of select core categories they believe the world may be constructed from, presumably because they take them as irreducible.
Aristotle had what now appears a slightly quirky taxonomy of forms, I believe, which includes things like shape and number. (Maybe today we can see it as more of an ontology of cognition than of the world).
Set theorists and logicians like Russell and Frege attempted to build not the entire world, but at least the entire world of logical truth and mathematics, from some very elemental… “stuff” for lack of a better term - what can be thought of as fundamental “content” or “structure”, which generates more structure. I think of these as either fundamental cognitive operations, or fundamental metaphysical operations. (That is, it’s not clear to me if rudimentary ideas like “there exist two mutually distinguishable things” is a noumenal or a phenomenal judgment.)
David Chalmers presented an approach to world-defining with a few features I hadn’t seen before (in “Constructing the World”), which could maybe be called perspectivism - it included ideas that not only is there ‘time’, but there is also an implicit now, whenever someone makes any kind of judgment.
Pierre Levy’s information-economy meta-language is based on an ontology I would call deeply ‘phenomenological’. I believe it draws from the work of semioticians, especially Deleuze and Guattari, and also C.S. Pierce. It tries to classify primary axes of consciousness and of how subjects experience ‘meaning’, including fundamentals like ‘nothingness’.
I am interested in an ontology which classifies types of knowledge, drawing from a deep, perhaps Kantian, analysis of judgment.
I don’t know enough about this topic, but one can imagine there are theories analyzing to what extent there is any inner human faculty of “pure reason”, and how it interacts with “sensory perception” (again, if there is such a thing).
This would assist us in distinguishing between different classes of “truth” altogether.
I can only give the superficial examples of things like the difference between “fact” and “opinion”, “subjective” vs. “objective”, or how some natural languages have an “evidential” mood where they indicate if knowledge is first-hand or second-hand.
I’d like to know some reference materials which could help me see how a collection of notions built from axioms would always be meticulously classified in what kind of judgment they are.

It sounds like you want a Kantian model of the mind, some modern research in this vein is reviewed in SEP. For neuroscience based approaches, see Khalidi,  Cognitive Ontology, Poldrack et al., Cognitive Atlas and Murtazina-Avdeenko, The constructing of cognitive functions ontology.

It seems to me you are misusing ontology vs metaphysics vs epistemology, etc., and of what these give categories (of understanding vs reality vs knowledge, etc.).  But all the more so if you eventually just make it boil down to "axioms and derivations", how is it not just some mathematical logic at best, i.e. a plain symbolic game, with no import at all on anything else, except maybe on the stories we tell and how and why they even work...
